# How to use last commit message in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am running my Jenkins pipeline in Windows slave and the pipeline is triggering through Git Polling. I want to add the last Git commit message in my email which is triggering in the last step of my pipeline.

I have tried below code snippet, but I'm getting this error message in the logs:

> fatal: invalid --pretty format: B

I can see the commit message in my logs. Is there any way we can directly use the commit message in the pipeline step?

```groovy
script{
    env.GIT_COMMIT_MSG = bat (script: 'git log -1 --pretty=%B ${GIT_COMMIT}', returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```

Comment: First, Groovy does no string interpolation when single quotes (`'`) are used, so your `${GIT_COMMIT}` isn't replaced with whatever it is but sent as is. Second, seeing you are on Windows, `%` is a reserved sign there, so you might want to escape it.

Comment: git log --format=format:%s -1 added stn gradle.properties . I am getting the Git command as well in the mail which is not required. Below is the code which I used " env.GIT_COMMIT_MSG = bat (script: "git log --format=format:%%s -1", returnStdout: true).trim()"